# can we somehow pass the parameter string inside constructor of interceptor in nestjs, making it more general and configurable?

Tags: nestjs, interceptor

I am using the following interceptor to transform the `gameLevel` from string to number.

```
@Injectable()
export class EnumStringToNumberInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor() {}
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => {
            if (data && data.list) {
                data.list.forEach(d => {
                    d['gameLevel'] = Number(d['gameLevel']);
                })
            } else if (data && data.gameLevel) {
                data['gameLevel'] = Number(data['gameLevel']);
            }
            return data;
        }));
      }
}
```

I want to pass `gameLevel` as key somehow in constructor something like the following -

```
constructor(private readonly key: string) {}

// and do something like this
d[key] = Number(d[key]);
```

By achieving this I will be making this interceptor more general to use it in different such use cases when key will be differing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nothing being injected into the interceptor, then a simple `new Interceptor('key or whatever string')` works well.

If you *do* have something being injected, I would suggest making use of reflection [and following Nest's docs on setting up custom metadata](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata) that the interceptor can read at runtime.

Something along the lines of

```js
export const GameLevel = (key: string) => SetMetadata('GAME_LEVEL_METADATA', key);
```

Then  in your controller you can use `@GameLevel('someLevelKey')` and in the interceptor you can do something along the lines of

```js
@Injectable()
export class EnumStringToNumberInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const level = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride('GAME_LEVEL_METADAT', [context.getClass(), context.getHandler()]);
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => {
            if (data && data.list) {
                data.list.forEach(d => {
                    d[level] = Number(d[level]);
                })
            } else if (data && data[level]) {
                data[level] = Number(data[level]);
            }
            return data;
        }));
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay McDoniel. You saved me. I was struglling with this for long. Reflector really did amazing.